# Capture Neo4j detailed logs

Tags: neo4j

I have develop a server plugin. 
Is there any way to get detail log.
There is a `console.log` but it only shows server shutdown and start up logs.

Answer (score 0):

What about standard logger? It's writing to `neo4j.0.0.log`.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());

logger.info("My tech info")
```

Comment: will it write to neo4j.0.0 log ?? but how ? I haven't mentioned file name anywhere :)

Comment: I don't understand your question.